Upgrading from Spring boot 2 to 3 and Hibernate 6 geometry column throwing type cast Exception
After upgrading from Spring boot 2 to 3 and hibernate, facing an error while fetching the geo point
Class:
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
...

@Entity
@Table(
        name = "location_log",
        schema = "delivery_location_log"
)
public class LocationLogEntity {

...

@Column(name = "point", columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
private Point point;

even the database has the same column name
error:
operator is not unique: delivery_location_log.geometry = delivery_location_log.geometry  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.  Position: 299
    {"stack_trace":"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select xxx from delivery_location_log.location_log lle1_0 where lle1_0.point in (?) ] [ERROR: operator is not unique: delivery_location_log.geometry = delivery_location_log.geometry\n  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.  Position: 299] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:277)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550
org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)
org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy213.findByDeliveryInAndProviderNameInAndPointInAndTimestampIn(Unknown Source)
om.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService.lambda$getEntitiesByKeys$0(LocationLogService.java:114)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService.lambda$getEntitiesByKeys$1(LocationLogService.java:113)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService.lambda$getEntitiesByKeys$2(LocationLogService.java:112)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService.lambda$getEntitiesByKeys$3(LocationLogService.java:111)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService.getEntitiesByKeys(LocationLogService.java:110)
com.aap.data.mapper.AbstractNaturalEntityMapper.mapEntities(AbstractNaturalEntityMapper.java:52)\n\tat com.aap.data.mapper.CreateEntityMapper.createOrGetEntities(CreateEntityMapper.java:117)
com.aap.data.mapper.CreateEntityMapper.createOrGetEntity(CreateEntityMapper.java:57)\n\tat com.aap.data.mapper.CreateEntityMapper.createOrGetEntity(CreateEntityMapper.java:37
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)\n\tat org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.LocationLogService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createOrGetEntity(<generated>)
com.aap.deliverylocationlog.service.EventsRawEventTopicProcessor.processRawEvent(EventsRawEventTopicProcessor.java:106)
 com.aap.deliverylocationlog.kafka.EventsRawEventTopicConsumer.listen(EventsRawEventTopicConsumer.java:58)\n\tat jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source)
 

As mentioned in the migration doc removed dialect
version used Hibernate 6.4.1 and Spring boot 3.2.2, Do I need to explicit cast then how? any leads are much appreciated.

Can you show the code for the query? The SQL that is generated is invalid. the in operator doesn't work on Point data. I think that is why you get that exception. The root cause, however, is a function that causes invalid SQL to be generated.
